# Two-Dimensional Arrays with pointers and regular ones? (in C)

Tags: c, arrays

In two dimensional arrays

```
arr[a][b] = *((int *)arr + a * numberOfColumns + b))
```

If you haven't seen this before, the pointer arithmetic of adding the scalar 
works as follows:

ex) `(3*2 + 2)` will add to `8` which is equivalent to `&(arr[8])` -- (although it must be written as `(3*2 + 2)`)

Does the second method have any advantage over the first method.

Code using `x[a][b]` method:

```
void SortHand(int arr[][2]);

void main()
{
    int firstArray[5][2] = { { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 } };
    SortHand(firstArray);
    printf("%d", firstArray[3][0]);
    while (!_kbhit());
}

void SortHand(int firstArray[][2])
{
    firstArray[3][0] = 14;
}
```

Code using `*((int *)arr + a * numberOfColumns + b))` method

```
void SortHand(int *arr[]);

void main()
{
    int numberOfColumns = 2;
    int arr[][2] = { { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 } };
    SortHand((int **)arr);
    printf("Number: %d", *((int *)arr + 3 * numberOfColumns + 0));
    while (!_kbhit());
}

void SortHand(int *arr[])
{
    int numberOfColumns = 2;
    int rowNumber = 3;
    int columnNumber = 0;

    *((int *)arr + 3 * numberOfColumns + 0) = 14;
}
```

Comment: The fact that you need those casts in the second method is a good indication that the types you're declared are wrong.

Comment: The second method is decidedly less readable, IMHO.

Comment: The second approach is also more verbose, and easier to mess up.  I can't imagine why anyone would prefer it, or what advantage it could possibly have.  Did *you* have some specific idea about that?

Comment: From a strict reading of the C standard, it's not entirely clear that the second form has defined behaviour; addition to a pointer which points to an array element must not exceed the bounds of the array (except that it is legal to point "one past the end"). Your code potentially goes past the bounds of the "innermost" array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In two dimensional arrays
>
> `arr[a][b] = *((int *)arr + a * numberOfColumns + b))`

That's not quite right; it's actually

```
arr[a][b] == *(*(arr + a) + b)
```

Your version assumes rows are contiguous, which may not be the case for certain dynamically-allocated arrays.

> Does the second method have any advantage over the first method.

No.

It's harder to read, harder to write, *much* easier to get wrong, and likely offers no performance benefit.  It will also fall down hard for non-contiguous arrays allocated like

```
T **arr = malloc( sizeof *arr * N );
if ( arr )
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
  {
    arr[i] = malloc( sizeof *arr[i] * M );
  }
}
```

since the rows won't be adjacent in memory, yet `arr[i][j]` will always do the right thing.

The subscript operator exists for a reason - might as well use it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such advantage of using pointer arithmetic, its just another way of doing accessing array.
However the first case is easy to write and debug.